# PHP for email contact form

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

Hi im having problems with my PHP code for sending an email via a contact form. I am getting no errors and can see no problem with the code after researching it thoroughly, could someone help me??

```
<?php

// Define some constants
define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "Nuim Buzz" );
define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "nuimbuzz@gmail.com" );
define( "EMAIL_SUBJECT", "Visitor Message" );

// Read the form values
$success = false;
$senderName = isset( $_POST['senderName'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/",   "", $_POST['senderName'] ) : "";
$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['senderEmail'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderEmail'] ) : "";
$senderMessage = isset( $_POST['senderMessage'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['senderMessage'] ) : "";

// If all values exist, send the email
if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $senderMessage ) {
  $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
  $headers = "From: " . $senderName . " <" . $senderEmail . ">";
  $success = mail( $recipient, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $senderMessage, $headers );
}


?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Thanks!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php if ( $success ) echo "<p>Thanks for sending your message! We'll get back to you shortly.</p>" ?>
  <?php if ( !$success ) echo "<p>There was a problem sending your message. Please try again.</p>" ?>
  <p>Click your browser's Back button to return to the page.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The HTML code:

```
  <h2>Send us an email...</h2>

  <ul>

    <li>
      <label for='senderName'>Your Name</label>
      <input type='text' name='senderName' id='senderName' placeholder='Please type your name...' required='required' maxlength='40' />
</li>

<li>
  <label for='senderEmail'>Your Email Address</label>
  <input type='email' name='senderEmail' id='senderEmail' placeholder='Please type your email address...' required='required' maxlength='50' />
</li>

<li>
  <label for='message' style='padding-top: .5em;'>Your Message</label>
  <textarea name='senderMessage' id='message' placeholder='Please type your message...' required='required' cols='80' rows='10' maxlength='10000'></textarea>
</li>

  </ul>

  <div id='formButtons'>
    <input type='submit' id='sendMessage' name='sendMessage' value='Send Email' />

  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Have you done any kind of test to see if it's getting inside the IF statement for sending the email?  An quick and dirty way I do that is inside that loop add: echo "HIT";

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You get the "There was a problem"? status message? Are you on a Windows or Unix/Linux host? mail() will return false if the local mail server is misconfigured, has outright reject your message, or doesn't exist at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your problem is server setup. Are you local? Are you on a shared hosting plan? If the latter you may have a domain problem, so contact your hosting solution to ensure you have it set up right. Also check your server error logs.

Comment: thanks just figured out i need a paid domain in order to set up email through my host, oh well, thanks guys

Comment: Guess how I knew, it happened to me once too ;)

Comment: haha well im lucky it did or i would have wasted even more time on it :P thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you're running this locally, in that case you'll need to set up a local mail server.

Also, `if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $senderMessage )` will fail if any of those variables, like for example `$senderMessage`, is `"0"`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find `<form>`. May it cause problems.